# En Python, en el Método Index, Por qué al correrla no me da el 5 como respuesta? Se queda en blanco o sea vacío. Ver el detalle adjunto

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
pets = "Cats & Dogs"
pets.index("&")
```

La respuesta es: 5 pero al correrla no me da el 5 como respuesta, o sea, se queda en blanco o sea vacío.
Agradezco la asistencia que me puedan brindar.

Comment: ¿ Que significa `se queda en blanco` ? No veo que tengas ningún `print( )` ni uses el resultado para nada. Deberías consultar lo que es un [mcve]. Un saludoo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`index` calcula el indice, pero como tú no lo usas para nada, lo descarta.

Si quieres imprimir el valor, usa

```
pets = "Cats & Dogs"
print(pets.index("&"))
```

y veras que es efectivamente cinco.